# Convert jpg to png and assign to image control

Tags: c#, .net, oop, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm passing images between pages. But on the second page I want to convert image which is jpg to png with transparent background. 
Finally I want to assign converted image to Image control, but I have error with implicitly convert type.

Here is my code:

First page:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(logoQrCodeImage, null);
Byte[] array = ConvertImage.ConvertToBytes(wb);
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State"))
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = array;
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

Second page:

```
Byte[] array = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] as Byte[];
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(50, 50);
//wb.LoadJpeg(stream);

var encoder = new PngEncoder();
MemoryStream pngStream = new MemoryStream();
ExtendedImage myImage;
myImage = wb.ToImage();
encoder.Encode(myImage, stream);

icon.Source = myImage; //ERROR

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("State");
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

I'm using ImageTools library.

Error message:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ImageTools.ExtendedImage' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/274445) library to create a WriteableBitmap.

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(50, 50);
wb.FromByteArray(array);

icon.Source = wb;
```

You can get the WriteableBitmapEx library from [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx).

Comment: Now the image is fuzzy completely wrong sent. Something like the same lines in different colors.

Comment: I would use the ToByteArray extension method provided in WriteableBitmapEx and then the FromByteArray method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `ExtendedImage` if you want to assign it to your Image control:

```
icon.Source = myImage.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: @user2962457 Well, the code you've posted doesn't make much sense. You're retrieving the bitmap's binary data, putting it in a WriteableBitmap, then saving it in a png. At that point, you could assign directly the WriteableBitmap to the Image control

Comment: Okay, but how can I put bitmap's binary data in a WriteableBitmap with transparent background ?

Comment: @user2962457 In the WriteableBitmap, pixels are stored in ARGB. That is: alpha, red, green, blue. By altering the value of the alpha channel, you can change the transparency of the pixel